# how to get child data of json Object

Tags: javascript, json

Ive got this JSON object Im trying loop through which is returned via a Netsuite script.

its returning a JSON object that has some child elements.

Im trying to get the caption for classnoheirachy - name data, but everything im just not sure how to get the inner most child.

Id like to know how in javascript I can output the classnoheirachy - name and classnoheiracy-internalId

My code is below for how im looping it at the moment, but if anyone knows how i can get the items above into this newly created array that would be greatly appreciated.

```
var rs = nlapiSearchRecord('item', 'customsearch_pm_item_record_loader', itemFilters);

response.write(JSON.stringify(rs));

var retObj = [];
for ( var i = 0; rs != null && i < rs.length; i++) {            
    var rowObj = {};
    rowObj.LOCATION = rs[i].getValue('location');
    rowObj.LOCATION_AVAILABLE = rs[i].getValue('locationquantityavailable');
    rowObj.CLASS = rs[i].getValue('classnohierarchy');
    rowObj.CURRENCY = rs[i].getValue('currency', 'pricing');
    rowObj.UNIT_PRICE = rs[i].getValue('unitprice', 'pricing');
    rowObj.LOCATION_ON_HAND = rs[i].getValue('locationquantityonhand');
    rowObj.ITEM = rs[i].getValue('itemid');
    rowObj.ITEM_NAME = rs[i].getValue('itemid');
    rowObj.PRICE_LEVEL = rs[i].getValue('pricelevel', 'pricing');
    rowObj.ITEM_DESCRIPTION = rs[i].getValue('salesdescription');
    retObj.push(rowObj);
}
```

[image: Image output of the array below]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
rowObj.Name = rs[i]['columns']['classnohierarchy']['name'];
rowObj.InternalId = rs[i]['columns']['classnohierarchy']['internalid'];
```

See Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnellesen/dPXK6/) for an example